# Terraform VPC Security Group issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am running into issues when I run terraform apply. The security group is attached to the ALB and ASG, and I can't figure out why I keep getting an error.

I am using this link as a guide: https://aws.plainenglish.io/deploy-a-highly-available-group-of-ec2-instances-using-terraform-bc37daf1a33f

Error messages below.

```
# Build a VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "main_vpc" {
 cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  
 tags = {
   Name = "Example_VPC"
 }
}

# Build ec2 instance
resource "aws_instance" "example_server" {
  ami           = "ami-0171207a7acd2a570"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
  key_name = aws_key_pair.PublicKey.id
  

  tags = {
    Name = "example_server1"
  }
}

# Adding and assigning 1st EIP to the above EC2 instance
resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
  instance = aws_instance.example_server.id
  domain = "vpc"

  tags = {
    name = "Elastic_IP1"
 }
}

# Build 2nd EC2 instance
#resource "aws_instance" "example_server2" {
#  ami           = "ami-0171207a7acd2a570"
#  instance_type = "t2.micro"
#  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
#  key_name = aws_key_pair.PublicKey.id

# tags = {
#    Name = "example_server2"
# }
#}


# Adding and assigning 2nd EIP to 2nd EC2 instance
#resource "aws_eip" "eip1" {
# instance = aws_instance.example_server2.id
#  domain = "vpc"

#  tags = {
#    name = "Elastic_IP2"
#  }
#}


# Public key
resource "aws_key_pair" "PublicKey" {
  key_name   = "Pubkey"
  public_key = "removed for obvious reasons"

 tags =  {
  name = "_PublicKey"
 }

}

# Security group to allow 443 and ssh access
resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
name = "main_sg"
egress { 
  from_port = 443
  to_port = 443
  protocol  = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks =  ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

egress { 
  from_port = 22
  to_port = 22
  protocol  = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks =  ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}


ingress {
from_port = 0
to_port   = 0
protocol  = "-1"
cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}


tags = {
Name = "main_SG"
}

}

# Private subnet setup for eu-west-2a
resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
  tags = {
    Name = "private-subnet-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet-2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"


  tags = {
    Name = "private-subnet-2"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
  cidr_block = "10.0.3.0/24"


  tags = {
    Name = "public-subnet-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"
  cidr_block = "10.0.4.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "public-subnet-2"
  }
}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "IGW" {
  vpc_id  = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "InternetGateWay"
    }
}

# adding route table to 
resource "aws_route_table" "second_routetable" {
 vpc_id  = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
 
 route {
   cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
   gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.IGW.id
 }
 
 tags = {
   Name = "2nd Route Table"
 }
}

# Route table association to public subnet 1
resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public-subnet-1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.second_routetable.id
}

# Route table association to public subnet 2
resource "aws_route_table_association" "b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public-subnet-2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.second_routetable.id
}

# Load balancer setup
resource "aws_lb" "my_alb" {
  name               = "my-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.public-subnet-1.id, aws_subnet.public-subnet-2.id]
}

# Listener for load-balancer
resource "aws_lb_listener" "my_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.my_alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.targetgroup.arn
  }
}

# Target group for ALB which is set up in the above code under target_group
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "targetgroup" {
  name     = "targetgroup"
  target_type = "instance"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
}


# Auto scaling group build
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my_asg" {
  name                      = "my_asg"
  max_size                  = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  health_check_type         = "ELB"    # optional
  desired_capacity          = 1
  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.targetgroup.arn]

  vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.public-subnet-1.id, aws_subnet.public-subnet-2.id]
  
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.my_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}

#launch template for ASG
resource "aws_launch_template" "my_launch_template" {

  name = "my_launch_template"
  
  image_id = "ami-0171207a7acd2a570"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "ubuntu"
  
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 8
      volume_type = "gp2"
    }
  }

  network_interfaces {
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
  }
}

# scale up policy for ASG
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "scale_up" {
  name                   = "scale_up"
  policy_type            = "SimpleScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.my_asg.name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  scaling_adjustment     = "1"      # add one instance
  cooldown               = "300"    # cooldown period after scaling
}

# scale down policy for ASG

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "scale_down" {
  name                   = "asg-scale-down"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.my_asg.name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  scaling_adjustment     = "-1"
  cooldown               = "300"
  policy_type            = "SimpleScaling"
}
```

**Error messages**

```
 Error: creating ELBv2 application Load Balancer (my-alb): InvalidConfigurationRequest: Security group 'sg-0e8f2bc7831c8bf82' does not belong to VPC 'vpc-0560a9556c0803e0a'
│       status code: 400, request id: d262046c-58f9-4510-8a8b-0997a85415d7
│
│   with aws_lb.my_alb,
│   on main.tf line 178, in resource "aws_lb" "my_alb":
│  178: resource "aws_lb" "my_alb" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: creating Auto Scaling Group (my_asg): ValidationError: One or more security groups in the launch template are not linked to the VPCs configured in the Auto Scaling group       
│       status code: 400, request id: 5e09990a-0969-4098-b5ed-df46affedd1b
│
│   with aws_autoscaling_group.my_asg,
│   on main.tf line 209, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my_asg":
│  209: resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my_asg" {
```

Comment: Typo: `public_key = "ssh-rsa `

Comment: I manually deleted text from the pub key as it contained names etc.

Comment: OK, but you should fix your post so that it's at least somewhat representative.

Comment: I understand. I made the change. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying the `vpc_id` on the security group. From [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group):

> `vpc_id` - (Optional, Forces new resource) VPC ID. Defaults to the region's default VPC.

Since you didn't specify the VPC, the security group belongs to the default VPC, not the VPC all your resources are in.

Comment: Thank you. I added the vpc_id argument in and it seemed to work but I am now getting this error:

'''
 Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameter: Security group sg-051405ba6b01b3c3d and subnet subnet-00b2c6252c769b3a7 belong to different networks.
│       status code: 400, request id: 14682e87-7f0d-4c05-9cd3-44dcbf17acbb
│
│   with aws_instance.example_server,
│   on main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_instance" "example_server":
│   11: resource "aws_instance" "example_server" 
 
'''

I could create ec2 instances without this issue before.

Comment: solved it!

I added 'subnet_id = aws_subnet.private-subnet-1.id' to the aws_instance resource.